# Merge posts of more than one site by using one database with the WordPress network

Tags: multisite

We try to merge the posts of more than one site by using one database, knowing that we use the WordPress network.
Within the WordPress network, each site has its own tabs.
We tried to modify the source of displaying posts to the main site.
An error occurs that I could not solve is that inside

> wp_posts

this table is in the database.
Posts, pages, part of the menu, and many other things.
I want to know who controls this and how to display only posts from a specific table in database.
We have a large number of WordPress sites trying to integrate the database of posts, tags, media and categories without pages, menu, theme settings and home page. We use the WordPress network.

**The goal is** to reduce server resources and publish the post on all sites at the same moment.

I modified the `wpdb.php` file, but this modification merged everything from the theme settings pages and this caused problems with the layout of the sites.

Comment: You're not going to be able to query posts from all sites at once, since each site on a network has its own posts table. If you want to sync content between sites you'll need something like https://distributorplugin.com.

Comment: Also, never _ever_ edit core WordPress files.